# run as>android application in eclipse giving no response

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android programming on eclipse and just doing it as a hobby...I have made and run 2 apps successfully and so their is no question of me not knowing how to run the app...i have restarted my pc but the problem sill persists..my 2 apps are still working on pressing the run button and i am using a device to run them(not an AVD) but the third app is not working...in fact their is no response..their are no errors in code but 3 lint warnings..the program is very simple(taking 2 numbers from user and displaying the sum)...Please help.MY code is as following:

```
package com.example.app3;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivityapp3 extends ActionBarActivity {
int num1,num2,sum;
Button button1;
EditText textf1,textf2;
TextView textv3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activityapp3);
    textf1=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
    textf2=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textv3=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    button1=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(textf1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(textf2.getText().toString());
            sum = num1 + num2;
            textv3.setText("sum" + "");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activityapp3, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: I am afraid from this code it is not possible to say anything you might want to post screenshot of progress, console and logcat. you can find them in  Window > Show View > ...

Comment: @ridoy yup,nothing new there except from a previous app run.

Comment: @setu stack overflow says i need reputation for that

Comment: You might want to add some details in the question. i.e what is written in the console window and what is progress window displaying.

Comment: phew...after hours of headache finally the problem is solved...thank you all for your interest...the problem was solved from run configuration where i dont know how but the launch action was set to do nothing for this app only

Answer (score 0):

Would really need to see the output of logcat. You can find it in the DDMS tabs of Eclipse.

Anyway, without more information I would ask: did you remember changing the activity name in AndroidManifest?

Comment: in which of the categories should i look into i mean like verbose,errors,info or something else

Comment: Most probably, the "errors" category. But you may have to end up reading the last 50 lines (there you should see the relevant info)